# Keep getting InputMismatchException

Tags: java

I have a project for an intro to Java course and I keep getting an InputMismatchException. Two grading assistants could not find the problem, so hopefully someone here can! The program uses a document as an input and for some reason is reading it wrong. Attached is a zip file with the input file and all of the classes (although you will probably just need the main class). Also attached are the instructions given by the course. Thanks!

Code where it seems to go wrong:

```
 private OnlineStudent readOnlineStudent(Scanner pIn) {
    String id = pIn.next();
    String lname = pIn.next();
    String fname = pIn.next();

    OnlineStudent student = new OnlineStudent(id, fname, lname);

    String fee  =  pIn.next();
     - Line 160 > int credits = pIn.nextInt();

    if (fee.equals("T")) student.setTechFee(true);
    else student.setTechFee(false);

    student.setCredits(credits);

    return student;
}
```

Here is the text of the input document:

```
C 8230123345450 Flintstone Fred R 0 12
C 3873472785863 Simpson Lisa N 750 18 
C 4834324308675 Jetson George R 0 20 
O 1384349045225 Szyslak Moe - 6
O 5627238253456 Flanders Ned T 3
```

Stack Trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at Main.readOnlineStudent(Main.java:160)
    at Main.readFile(Main.java:84)
    at Main.run(Main.java:189)
    at Main.main(Main.java:31)
```

Link to google drive folder with code and document:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rjiXoB-rBd1FQdQQqbGMGL_a1kWd1v_Z

Comment: Post the relevant code here, don't ask us to download some code. Also post the exact stacktrace

Comment: if the code sample is too big make use of pastebin.com

Comment: @JonathanZier chances are, we 'll be able to spot the issue as soon as you show the stacktrace. just the text of the input won't tell us anything, because we won't have any idea as to what type of variable you are trying to map/cast it to

Comment: Hopefully this is more helpful!

Comment: I think you are missing a next() before the nextInt(). have you debugged to check what the values are you've read so far? An easier approach would be to read every line in it's entirely, and split it up in your code

Comment: It should be correct, I have tried adding a new string variable in case I am missing, but that does not solve the problem. This method is called after the scanner already calls the first String so it should be fine.

Comment: have you debugged your code?

Comment: Yes I have, and so have 2 grading assistants...

Comment: So, 2 grading assistants have executed this code in debug mode, and couldn't manage to find the problem?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Something is fishy about your story...ok post us screenshot when you're in debug mode, caught breakpoint on the line that throws the exception(160) and values inside in `pIn` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the main class line 80 , you should use the equals method , not "==" . It makes scanner read the wrong type;

Comment: Yes! Thanks! That did it!

Answer (score 0):

See how your input matches to reading values.

```
    String id = pIn.next();  // C
    String lname = pIn.next(); //8230123345450
    String fname = pIn.next(); //Flintstone

    OnlineStudent student = new OnlineStudent(id, fname, lname);

    String fee  =  pIn.next(); //Fred
    int credits = pIn.nextInt(); // R --->this is not an integer
```

You must have another next() for R value.

Comment: he stated there is already a next() call before the Scanner gets to that method